# I am curious about the interpretation of the elastic Net coefficient

Tags: python, scikit-learn, elastic-net

I want to discover the importance of variables in data through sklearn's Elactic Net. But I don't understand the exact meaning of coefficient. When training, I used alpha: 0.01585598, l1_ratio: 1.000.
The graph below is a coefficient graph drawn from my data. My goal is to predict "Time Spend" through various variables. Please understand that the column names are marked with A, B, C, and D due to personal information.
[image]

In the graph, what does variable "A" mean for coefficients greater than 150? Do I need to understand that using variable "A" takes more than 150 seconds when predicting "Time Spend"? Or does it just mean that variable "A" has a high positive correlation with the value of "y"? I drew a coefficient graph through learning, but I am asking a question to understand the meaning accurately.
Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 1):

A linear model is in the form of:

$y = a\cdot x_1 + b\cdot x_2 + c\cdot x_3.....$

Where $x_n$ is the feature and the letters a,b,c, is the coefficient.

In your figure you are plotting the coefficient a,b,c...

Lets say that you coefficients are $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=10$

If you feature are
$x_1=0$, $x_2=10$ and $x_3 = 1$

then your prediction will be
$y = 1 \cdot 0 + 2 \cdot  10 + 10 \cdot 1 = 30$

> what does variable "A" mean for coefficients greater than 150?
> Nothing special, its just a multiplication.

> Do I need to understand that using variable "A" takes more than 150 seconds when predicting "Time Spend"?
> It has nothing to do with the computational time of the algorithm. It has to do with the meaning of the feature.